# Power Query - trying to remove a dynamic column that's created/updated when I access external data source

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

I have a table that's generated when I pull data from an accounting software - the example columns are months/years in the format as follows (It pulls all the way to current day, and the last month will be partial month data):

Nov_2020

Dec_2020

Jan_2021

Feb_1_10_2021 (Current month, column to remove)

... So on and so forth.

My goal I have been trying to figure out is how to use the power query editor to remove the last column (The partial month) - I tried messing around with the text length to no avail (The goal being to remove anything with text length >8, so the full months data would show but the last month shouldn't). I can't just remove based on a text filter, because if someone were to pull the data 1 year from now it would have to account for 2021/2022.

Is this possible to do in PQ? Sorry, I'm new to it so if I need to elaborate more I can.. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [Table.SelectColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-selectcolumns) where you use [List.Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/list-select) on the [Table.ColumnNames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-columnnames).

```
= Table.SelectColumns(
      PrevStep, 
      List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(PrevStep), each Text.Length(_) <= 8)
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Although both Alexis Olson's and Justyna MK's answers are valid, there is another approach. Since it appears that you're getting data for each month in a separate column, what you will surely want to do is unpivot your data, that is transform those columns into rows. It's the only sensible way to get a good material for analysis, therefore, I would suggest to unpivot the columns first, then simply filter out rows containing the last month.

To make it dynamic, I would use unpivot other columns option - you select columns and it will transform remaining columns into row in such a way that two columns will be created - one that will contain column names in rows and the other one will contain values.

[image]

To illustrate what I mean by unpivoting, when you have data like this:

[image]

You're automatically transforming that into this:

[image]

Comment: This one's a little more involved but it worked as well - thank you!!

Comment: @alrightaaa, I agree that unpivoting is a good idea. You can use the `Text.Length` condition to filter either before or after unpivoting, whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do it through Power Query's Advanced Editor. Assign the name of the last column to `LastColumn` variable and then use it in the last step (`Removed Columns`).

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(Excel file path), null, true),
    tblPQ_Table = Source{[Item="tblPQ",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(tblPQ_Table,{{"Nov_2020", Int64.Type}, {"Dec_2020", Int64.Type}, {"Jan_2021", Int64.Type}, {"Feb_1_10_2021", Int64.Type}}),
    LastColumn = List.Last(Table.ColumnNames(#"Changed Type")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{LastColumn})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: This solution worked as well - thanks!! :)